# How to disable "click" while keyframe animation / and enable when it finish?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, click, toggleclass

I have a conflict with my css Keyframe animation and JavaScript - here http://district52.ru

I want to disable the clicking function on my 'CRUZ' - until it puts on the final position.

How to disable "click" until the keyframe stops? And after to enable it?

P.S.: I don't want the javascript function to start until the keyframe ends!

Thanks Ahead,
Oscar.

Comment: Your link is no longer available, so I can no longer review the question to edit my answer. If my answer helped you in the past, please mark it as the solution. Otherwise, post the solution you found to help other visitors that might have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the demo page and it looks like your keyframe animation is not a loop; you can achieve what you want with simple CSS3 transitions. If you are using jQuery you could do something like this:

```
$("#cruz").on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function () {
   $(this).addClass("finished");
});
$("#cruz").click(function () {
    if ( !$(this).hasClass("finished") ) return;
    // Here goes the code that will execute if it's not animating
    // Remember to remove the class which you use as filter ("finished")
});
```

You could also add a CSS rule to avoid the cursor from showing the "clickable" icon like this:

```
#cruz {
    cursor: initial;
}
#cruz.finished {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```